# TAR not excluding directories with date pattern

Tags: shell-script, tar

I've written this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=`date --rfc-3339=date`
CHECKDATE=`date --date "2 days ago" --rfc-3339=date`
FILENAME=$TODAY-package.tar

tar cvf $FILENAME --no-recursion --after-date $CHECKDATE *
tar uvf $FILENAME --after-date $CHECKDATE require plugin img
```

This should (at least in my intentions) create a .tar file with both files *and* directories modified *after* given date (which is 2 days before the script execution date) for what concerns root directory, and act recursively in case of *require*, *plugin* and *img* directories.

Problem is, it looks like to be correctly excluding older files, while it's adding *every single directory* to the .tar, even the oldest ones.

I've tried adding */* after the *, without success.

Any hints?

Comment: The ‘--after-date=date’ (‘--newer=date’, ‘-N date’) option causes tar to only work on files whose data modification or status change times are newer than the date given. If you only want tar to make the date comparison based on modification of the file's data (rather than status changes), then use the ‘--newer-mtime=date’ option.
so your command will be `tar cvf $FILENAME --no-recursion --newer-mtime $CHECKDATE *`

Comment: That's a good hint, I've modified the script as you suggested. Unfortunately it still adds *all* the directories regardless of the date, and I can't find a way to avoid it yet...

Comment: one easy solution is to use `find` command. for eg: create a test file and set it timestamp needed using `touch -t <timestamp> ` note: use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]. Now you can use 
`find <path to directory> -newer <path to test file>  -print0 | xargs -0 tar --no-recursion -cvf foo.tar`. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I've already dodged the problem by using _find . -maxdepth 1  -type f_. I've managed to modify the environment so that adding directories is no longer necessary. Not a real solution, but it removed the problem. Thanks to all anyway.